# IOXO M133-N Laptop / Chromebook - Touchpad Not Recognized

Tags: touchpad

Greetings and Salutations,

I installed Ubuntu in place of Neverware's Chromium. The M133-N is approved in their equipment list, yadda yadda.

Anyway, all installed fine except the trackpad is not recognized.

`less /proc/bus/input/devices` - gives this result:

```
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input16
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

So it appears to not recognize the touchpad hardware at all. Can someone please make a suggestion as to what I should do next?

Thanks Guys & Gals,

Pedro

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you've installed (1) the output of `sudo lsusb`. With this, it may be possible to confirm whether the touchpad can be used with Linux 

Answer (score 0):

The patch to fix the touchpad in the IOXO M133-N is here
https://github.com/neverware/kernel/commit/ca97a9d8132c7c37933ee13c38a9bca0fa51892a

you can patch the kernel in your distribution or find one where it was already implemented.

In response to your latest question. No, I would not recommend that you do it yourself unless you know well what you are doing. Try to search for "Trackpad ALPS not recognized by ioxo m133-n" to eventually find the patched kernel. Sorry that I can not be more direct but it appears that comments with links to other (very helpful) forum are not being permitted here.

Answer (score 0):

assuming i know nothing about adding this patch to the kernel is there a walk through of any sort to tell me what to do with the corresponding .c file that i've downloaded? google brings me a plethora of recompile this and rewrite that links. is installing a driver/patch really this difficult in debian/ubuntu based linux?

Comment: How is this an answer? It is or at least appears to be another question. If you have a question make a question do not try to add it as an answer.